# ZoKrates Invalid witness produces valid proof

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

I'm new to ZoKrates and ZK stuff in general. I am confused about how the witness works. If I compute an invalid witness the verifier still verifies the proof as correct. For example (based on ZoKrates "get started").

Given this program:

```
def main(private field a, field b) -> bool:
  return a * a == b
```

Then running the following:

```
zokrates compile -i root.zok
zokrates setup
zokrates compute-witness -a 337 113569
zokrates generate-proof
```

When I run

```
zokrates verify
```

It returns PASSED.

However if I provide a bad value to `compute-witness` it still passes. For example:

```
zokrates compute-witness -a 1 113569
zokrates generate-proof
zokrates verify // PASSES
```

I'm clearly miss-understanding something here but after spending a few hours reading different bits online I'm still not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised the understanding that I was missing and it is rather simple. The proof in this case is not verifying that `a * a` is equal to `b` but instead it is simply a proof that I have run the computation.

For example the following generates a proof that I have run this program with `a = 337` and `b = 113569` and the return value is `true`.

```
zokrates compute-witness -a 337 113569
zokrates generate-proof
```

If I change the inputs to make the computation return `false`; for example `a = 1` and `b = 113569`.
the following generates a proof that I have run this program with those values for `a` and `b` and the return was `false`.

```
zokrates compute-witness -a 1 113569
zokrates generate-proof
```

Thank you to Darko on [ZoKrates Gitter](https://gitter.im/ZoKrates/Lobby) for helping me understand this.